# C# MVC Web App using Azure AD randomly started redirecting about 10 times before failing

Tags: c#, azure, model-view-controller, active-directory

I wrote a web app for internal use in my company and it has not had a problem in the few months it's been live. On Friday, folks said they could no longer login any longer. Nothing in the code changed apart from some javascript. Nothing in Azure seemingly changed.

Here's what happens: I go through the normal procedure of entering my credentials, then I get redirected to the company's 2FA stuff. Once I pass that, it asks me if I want to stay logged in. From there, I can watch the URL in my address bar change about 10 times before finally just giving the famous "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again."

I am making sure to access the web app using HTTPS, btw. Anonymous login is set in Azure. I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated greatly!

Comment: Does this happen in Chrome or also in other browsers? Chrome had recently been updated and now blocks cookies in certain conditions that may apply here

Comment: You should open the developer console in Chrome and make sure to enable "preserve log" for both the console and the network tab. Usually the output during the redirects will give you enough of a clue for what is happening.

Comment: Chrome, IE, Edge, and Firefox. Same results.

Comment: is there some redirect setting that has been changed in IIS?

Comment: Not that we can tell.

Answer (score 0):

My boss figured it out late yesterday evening.

added a rewrite rule to system.webServer

```html
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=none;" />
          <conditions>
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="No SameSite">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=none" negate="true" />
          </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Exactly the issue I had. I had a similar rewrite rule but SameSite was set to "lax" and not "none" which caused the error on Azure AD. Thanks!